# Error running Vpython in Spyder (NameError: name 'gsprint' is not defined)

Tags: python, spyder, vpython

> NameError: name 'gsprint' is not defined

I repeatedly get this error message when trying to run this:

```
from vpython import *
box()
```

I am using Python 3.7.3 and Spyder 3.3.4, and cannot find any help in documentation. Vpython website says I should be able to run it:

https://vpython.org/presentation2018/install.html

Comment: How did you install vpython? What happens if you start Python at the command line and type the above code?

Comment: I used Anaconda to install Vpython. Running it from the Anaconda Commant Prompt actually works!

Comment: Try starting Spyder from the Anaconda command prompt. If you didn't install vpython in the base environment, install `spyder-kernels` in the same environment as vpython and `activate` that environment before starting Spyder.

Comment: Note that the installation info at vpython.org says that in order to use an up-to-date Spyder you MUST install vpython 7.5.0. Execute "conda list vpython" to check that you have vpython 7.5.0.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue: I kept getting these `"NameError: name 'gsprint' is not defined" error` messages when running codes with the `from vpython import *` line. Strangely, the same codes on Anaconda/Spyder in another computer were working fine.

I ended up in this page while looking for a solution. I tried the simple vpython code above and got the same error message running from spyder while it worked fine running directly in the Anaconda prompt. I checked that the vpython version in the environment is `7.5.0`.

My solution: an overall update on Anaconda

`conda update --all`

I'm now running with `Spyder 3.3.6` and `Python 3.7.3` and the code is working fine.