# VPython: How to fix "NameError: name '__server' is not defined"?

Tags: python, python-3.x, anaconda, vpython

I am having some trouble with VPython 7.6.1. Everytime I want to run a simple line of code I keep getting the same error:

```
NameError: name '__server' is not defined
```

Here is the code:

```
from vpython import *
box()
```

I have explored other posts but none of the solutions worked for me :

[Pyo in Python; name 'Server' not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51925947/pyo-in-python-name-server-not-defined)

[Error running Vpython in Spyder (NameError: name 'gsprint' is not defined)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56145089/error-running-vpython-in-spyder-nameerror-name-gsprint-is-not-defined)

I changed the name of the python file, I reinstalled Anaconda and updated my version of Python and VPython. I am using Spyder with Anaconda and Python 3.7.6.

Also, VPython uses TKinter for its graphics so I changed the graphic settings to TKinter, but still I get the same error.

Has it happened to anyone else here? Do you have any clues on how to fix it or on what it is that I am doing wrong here?

Here is the error in detail:

```
Python 3.7.6 (default, Jan  8 2020, 20:23:39) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)]
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

IPython 7.12.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python.

runfile('C:/Users/lponcin/Google Drive/simplex/code_orbito.py', wdir='C:/Users/lponcin/Google Drive/simplex')
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Users\lponcin\Google Drive\simplex\code_orbito.py", line 9, in <module>
    box()

  File "C:\Users\lponcin\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\vpython\vpython.py", line 1099, in __init__
    super(box, self).setup(args)

  File "C:\Users\lponcin\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\vpython\vpython.py", line 579, in setup
    super(standardAttributes, self).__init__()

  File "C:\Users\lponcin\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\vpython\vpython.py", line 236, in __init__
    from .no_notebook import _

  File "C:\Users\lponcin\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\vpython\no_notebook.py", line 272, in <module>
    __w = threading.Thread(target=__server.serve_forever)

NameError: name '__server' is not defined
```

Answer (score 0):

The __server is created at line 234 in the file

https://github.com/vpython/vpython-jupyter/blob/master/vpython/no_notebook.py

Perhaps you are getting an exception that is not being detected. Try removing the try except statements around this code where the server is created to see what the problem might be on your system.

Comment: I removed the try and exept statement from line 224 to 240 but still I got the same error

Comment: What do you see if you execute print(__server) just after its assignment to HTTPServer?

Comment: By the way, VPython does NOT use TKinter for its graphics; it uses the WebGL 3D graphics library that is a component of browsers. One other possibility: Did you install VPython with pip or with conda install -c vpython vpython (which is preferred)?

Comment: I'll comment that for VPython questions it's better to post to the VPython forum, where there are many more VPython users who will see your question than if you post to stackoverflow:

https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups&hl=en#!forum/vpython-users